# Finding Test set and Sub folder from a parent folder in QC Test Lab

Tags: hp-quality-center

I am trying to extract sub folders (not all children folders) along with Test sets(not all children test sets, only next test set) from a parent folder in QC test Lab.

Let suppose There are 2 sub folders and 1 test set in a Parent folder in QC:

```
   -Parent Folder1
      - Sub folder1
      - Sub folder2
      - Test Set
```

Using the below code i am able to extract the subfolders only not test sets:
Code:

```
Set TsetMgr = UserForm9.QCConnection.TestSetTreeManager  'object required
Set Root1p = TsetMgr.Root 'connect to Root
Set SubNodesRoot = Root1p.SubNodes() 'Using SubNodes method to extract SubNodes from QC
For rp = 1 To SubNodesRoot.Count 'Total SubNodes available
c1p = SubNodesRoot.Item(rp)' Finding SubNodes
MsgBox(c1p)  ' SubFolder1 and Subfolder2 values are displayed.
```

Next

My only problem now is, i am not able to extract Test Sets along with subfolders from a parent folder.

Can anyone please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: @GlennV, please stop editing questions simply to add a tag which has the same meaning as the existing tag. Instead, bring up the identical tags on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to get both folders and test sets with calling one function. But you can get the folders with the method you described. And you can get the immediate child-test-sets of a TestSetFolder via the TestSetFactory of this folder:

```
test_set_factory = lab_folder.TestSetFactory
test_sets = test_set_factory.NewList("")
test_sets.each do |test_set|
  puts "Test Set: #{test_set.Name}"
end
```

That should print you the names of all TestSets in the lab_folder. I think you cannot have TestSets directly in your root folder, so you can use the TestSetFactory only on sub folders.